# Wordpress - How to show a list of the current page children (title, content)?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a site with 3 category **pages**. Each one of these categories have a few **subpages**. For each category I want it to show the title and link for each subpage and maybe the featured image if that's possible.

```
CategoryA Page Example:
  Product1 (from CategoryA) Title
  Product2 (from CategoryA) Title
  Product3 (from CategoryA) Title
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer. :) In case someone stumbles upon this question here's what I did.

I made a new template called category with the following code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
    query_posts('post_type=page&post_parent='.$post->ID );
    if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>

<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

<pre><?php echo the_content(); ?></pre>

<?php
    endwhile; // end of the loop.
?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick addition:

You can also use:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('child_of='.$post->ID); ?>
```

to display a list of the current page's children.

Hope that helps!

Vq.